# Time comparison for TensorFlow operation and Numpy multiplication

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, tensorflow

I've been trying to optimize my computations; and for most operations that I've tried, `tensorflow` is much faster.  I'm trying to do a fairly simple operation...Transform a matrix (multiply each value by 1/2 and then add 1/2 to that value).

With the help of @mrry , I was able to do these operations in `tensorflow`.  However to my surprise, the `numpy` method was significantly faster?!

`tensorflow` seems like an extremely useful tool for data scientists and I think this could help clarify it's use and advantages.

**Am I not using `tensorflow` data structures and operations in the most efficient way?**  I'm not sure how non-tensorflow methods would be faster.  I'm using a Mid-2012 Macbook Air 4GB RAM

*trans1 is the tensorflow version while trans2 is numpy. DF_var is a pandas dataframe object*

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def trans1(DF_var):
    #Total user time is 31.8532807827 seconds

    #Create placeholder 
    T_feed = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,DF_var.shape)

    #Matrix transformation
    T_signed = tf.add(
                      tf.constant(0.5,dtype=tf.float32),
                      tf.mul(T_feed,tf.constant(0.5,dtype=tf.float32))
                      ) 

    #Get rid of of top triangle
    T_ones = tf.constant(np.tril(np.ones(DF_var.shape)),dtype=tf.float32)
    T_tril = tf.mul(T_signed,T_ones)

    #Start Graph Session
    sess = tf.Session()

    DF_signed = pd.DataFrame(
                          sess.run(T_tril,feed_dict={T_feed: DF_var.as_matrix()}),
                          columns = DF_var.columns, index = DF_var.index
                          )
    #Close Graph Session
    sess.close() 
    return(DF_signed)

def trans2(DF_var):
    #Total user time is 1.71233415604 seconds
    M_computed = np.tril(np.ones(DF_var.shape))*(0.5 + 0.5*DF_var.as_matrix())
    DF_signed = pd.DataFrame(M_computed,columns=DF_var.columns, index=DF_var.index)
    return(DF_signed)
```

My timing method was:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
#operation
print str(time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: Do you have a GPU on your system? If so, try `export TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT=800` to make it invisible (the default placer is naive and presence of GPU can make things slower)

Comment: Also, the CPU version is not competitive with well configured numpy (ie OpenBLAS) unless it's compiled with `-c opt -mavx`

Comment: Anaconda numpy on MacBook is crazy good. When I benchmarked Eigen (what tensorflow is based on), it was 25% slower than my MacBook numpy. But you should be able to get within 75% of numpy performance on CPU matmul with the right flags

Comment: When i was doing scipy's matrix exponentiation it was WAY slower than tensorflow's operation . I was hoping it was going to be a similar situation.

Comment: What size array are you using? I would expect that the relative performance between numpy and TF would vary based on the array size. It would also be informative to know if your numpy is performing vectorized computations.

Comment: Can you post more of the code?  In particular, if you're measuring the Tensorflow startup time, it's worth being aware that the *first* execution of TensorFlow typically takes longer (particularly on GPU, and double particularly if you're including the tf.Session() call, which sets up threads, etc.).  You might want to "warm the cache" for both by executing them once and *then* doing your timing.

In general, though, I'm not too surprised if TensorFlow is slower for a single primitive matrix multiply operation on CPU, for the reasons Yaroslav suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are compatible with the [benchmarks from another guy](https://simplyml.com/linear-algebra-shootout-numpy-vs-theano-vs-tensorflow-2/).

In his benchmark he compared NumPy, Theano and Tensorflow on

> an Intel core i5-4460 CPU with 16GiB RAM and a Nvidia GTX 970 with 4
>   GiB RAM using Theano 0.8.2, Tensorflow 0.11.0, CUDA 8.0 on Linux Mint
>   18

His results for addition shows that:
[image]

He also tested a few other functions such as matrix multiplication:

[image]

The results are:

> It is clear that the main strengths of Theano and TensorFlow are very
>   fast dot products and matrix exponents. The dot product is
>   approximately 8 and 7 times faster respectively with Theano/Tensorflow
>   compared to NumPy for the largest matrices. Strangely, matrix addition
>   is slow with the GPU libraries and NumPy is the fastest in these
>   tests.
>
> The minimum and mean of matrices are slow in Theano and quick in
>   Tensorflow. It is not clear why Theano is as slow (worse than NumPy)
>   for these operations.