# Why is TensorFlow matmul() much slower than NumPy multiply()?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

In the python code below, why is the time for multiplication via numpy much smaller than via tensorflow?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
size=10000
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(size, size))
y = tf.matmul(x, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  rand_array = np.random.rand(size, size)

  start_time = time.time()
  np.multiply(rand_array,rand_array)
  print("--- %s seconds numpy multiply ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

  start_time = time.time()
  sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: rand_array})
  print("--- %s seconds tensorflow---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The output is

```
--- 0.22089099884 seconds numpy multiply ---
--- 34.3198359013 seconds tensorflow---
```

Comment: I didn't observe such a staggering difference when I ran it, but `numpy` was roughly five times faster than `tensorflow`.

Comment: Another observation - I re-ran the `sess.run()` and I got a much faster result nearly as fast as `numpy`

Comment: @martianwars in my pc with re-run sess.run() time is not fast

Comment: I had to reduce the `size` a bit, maybe that could be a reason

Comment: I got --- 0.8210248947143555 seconds numpy multiply --- and --- 63.973095178604126 seconds tensorflow ---  or a factor of 77.9.  This was on a slow Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 @ 3.0GHz.

Comment: Similar findings have been reported before.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738854/time-comparison-for-tensorflow-operation-and-numpy-multiplication

Comment: BTW, those earlier findings were due to incorrect compilation setting which has since been fixed. There's a bug in code above (mul vs matmul), on fixing you get 0.22 (numpy) vs 0.42 (TF) . The extra time is due to copying of data from Python to TF. If you replace feed dict with variables, it becomes 0.22 (numpy) vs 0.16 (TF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, citing documentation:

> numpy.multiply(x1, x2[, out]) =  Multiply arguments
>   element-wise.

and

> tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=False, transpose_b=False,
>   a_is_sparse=False, b_is_sparse=False, name=None)
>
> Multiplies matrix a by matrix b, producing a * b.
>
> The inputs must be two-dimensional matrices, with matching inner
>   dimensions, possibly after transposition.

Which suggest that you compare different operations: O(n^2) pointwise multiplication with O(n^3) matrix multiplication. I corrected the test to use matrix multiplication 2 times in both cases:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
size=2000
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(size, size))
y = tf.matmul(x, x)
z = tf.matmul(y, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  rand_array = np.random.rand(size, size)

  start_time = time.time()
  for _ in xrange(10):
      np.dot(np.dot(rand_array,rand_array), rand_array)
  print("--- %s seconds numpy multiply ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

  start_time = time.time()
  for _ in xrange(10):
      sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: rand_array})
  print("--- %s seconds tensorflow---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and got the results:

```
--- 2.92911195755 seconds numpy multiply ---
--- 0.32932305336 seconds tensorflow---
```

using a fast GPU (gtx 1070).

Comment: numpy (with MKL) dot is 80% faster than tf.matmul (compiled with haswell march) on my test machine. Tested with a `(5000000, 100)` x `(100,)` matrix and vector. (need to add a few extra ops in tf to get the same result: `tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(a, tf.expand_dims(b, 0), transpose_b=True))`)